# Securely embedded Power BI reporting has no option for fullscreen

Tags: powerbi

When I publish my Power BI reporting to the web and embed it into my website with `allowFullScreen="true"`, I can see an icon on the bottom right which enables me to see it in fullscreen mode.

However, when I "Securely embed this report in a website or portal", Power BI gives me the iframe code with `allowFullScreen="true"` but this time I'm not able to see the icon.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Enter into fullscreen" button is part of the *Power BI Publish To Web* - unfortunately it is not available within the option *Securely embed this report in a website or portal*.

The `allowFullScreen="true"` has nothing to do with that and is an attribute of the html iframe tag.

Comment: It is not available yet full screen mode to embed report in secure web